# Unexpected and incorrect HEX codes coming from IR remote, but only in second function..?

Tags: arduino-uno, ir, remote-control, neopixel

Hello:) I'm working on a lil project with some NeoPixels being controlled by an IR remote, and with there being multiple strips, I felt it would be best to first select the desired strip, and then the colour. The code is getting there, albiet with a few bugs. I've set the serial monitor up for debugging.

When a strip is selected (I call them 'shift buttons', like on a keyboard), the program and serial monitor detect it flawlessly, every time. However, when I press ONLY a colour button to test the input, a seemingly random, HEX code pops up on the serial monitor which changes with each press. This seems to cause the whole code not to function past selecting a strip.

Would anyone be able to give me a hand as to why this incorrect code might be popping up please? I've tested the function of the buttons on a IR remote testing script and the buttons correlate to the HEX displayed everytime so I know the physical route to the Arduino isn't flawed

TL:DR:

One function with IR information works flawlessly, other function using the same info returns random(?) HEX codes

Below is the code:

```
#include <IRremote.h> //include IR library
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <FastLED.h> //include LED library
#define NUM_LEDS1 18 //say how many leds is in row 1
#define NUM_LEDS2 17 //say how many leds is in row 2
#define NUM_LEDS3 20 //say how many leds is in row 3
const int RECV_PIN = 8; //say what pin IR sensor is plugged into
const int LEDPIN = 13;//say what pin blue STATUS led is plugged into

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);
decode_results results;
unsigned long key_value = 0;
int shiftbutton = 0;

CRGB leds1[NUM_LEDS1]; //link leds1 with how many leds are in it
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS2]; //link leds2 with how many leds are in it
CRGB leds3[NUM_LEDS3]; //link leds3 with how many leds are in it
size_t NumLeds[3] = { NUM_LEDS1, NUM_LEDS2, NUM_LEDS3 };
CRGB* strips[3] = { leds1, leds2, leds3 };

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);

  irrecv.enableIRIn(); //Enables IR
  irrecv.blink13(true); //Flashes onboard LED when IR input detected
  pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT); //set signal led as an ourput
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 5>(leds1, NUM_LEDS1); //setup for row 1
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 3>(leds2, NUM_LEDS2); //setup for row 2
  FastLED.addLeds<NEOPIXEL, 6>(leds3, NUM_LEDS3); //setup for row 3
}

void loop()
{
  readIR();
  ShiftButtons();
  LEDStrip();
}

void readIR()
{
  if (irrecv.decode(&results))
  {
    // debug
    Serial.println("processing received IR");
    // if not repeat key
    if (results.value != 0XFFFFFFFF)
    {
      key_value = results.value;

      // debug
      Serial.print("using new value ");
      Serial.println(key_value, HEX);
    }
    else
    {
      // nothing to do
      // key_value still contains the result of the previous read

      // debug
      Serial.print("using old value ");
      Serial.println(key_value, HEX);
    }
    irrecv.resume();
  }
}

void ShiftButtons()
{
  switch (key_value)
  {
    case 0xFF30CF:
      shiftbutton = 1;
      break;
    case 0xFFB04F:
      shiftbutton = 2;
      break;
    case 0xFF708F:
      shiftbutton = 3;
      break;
  }

  // debug
  Serial.print("shiftbutton set to ");
  Serial.println(shiftbutton);
}

void setStrip (size_t index, CRGB color)
{
  fill_solid(strips[index], NumLeds[index], color);
  FastLED.show();
}

void LEDStrip()
{
  if (shiftbutton == 0) return; // no strip selected

  // debug
  Serial.print("LEDStrip: using key value ");
  Serial.println(key_value, HEX);

  CRGB color = CRGB::Black;
  switch (key_value)
  {
    case 0xFF1AE5:
      color = CRGB::Red;
      // debug
      Serial.println("color set to red");
      break;
    case 0xFF9A65:
      color = CRGB::Green;
      // debug
      Serial.println("color set to green");
      break;
    case 0xFFA25D:
      color = CRGB::Blue;
      // debug
      Serial.println("color set to blue");
      break;
  }

  setStrip(shiftbutton - 1, color);
  shiftbutton = 0;  // reset the flag
}
```

Hopefully I’ve attached that code right!
Thanks

Comment: What are you getting in `decode_type` of the results?

Comment: do the LEDs shine onto the IR sensor?

Comment: 19:44:59.050 -> LEDStrip: using key value FF30CF//meaning  (shift selected)
19:44:59.050 -> processing received IR//red pressed here
19:44:59.096 -> using new value 5A9FB1CA //picks up this or many other random codes
19:44:59.096 -> shiftbutton set to 0//resets shift select button even though successful colour hasn’t been selected

Comment: Also, no light shines directly into the sensor - it is working flawlessly when only the buttons to select strips are pressed, however when colours are introduced random numbers in the serial monitor start appearing instead of the set colour codes. Thanks

Comment: I would say, this code can not work at all. You read a value from the IR, then you check for "shiftbutton pressed" (1-3). In the next function you skip if no shiftbutton is pressed or you use the same key_value to select the color. But this is still the code for one of the shiftbuttons; not a color code.  So it would not match. Then the shifbutton is reset to 0. You allready have pressed the color key which might be in a queue. The loop starts from the beginning. Now (much too late) the color key is read. It does not match a shift button; shiftbutton stays with 0. And so on

Comment: But why the random values? Perhaps there is a unwanted shift when the bytes are tranfered induced by delayed reading. You could simply write a little test program. Use only the `readIR` method, but delete the else block (that would print too much output ;-) ). Then press the keys on the sender and see if the values are still random. Do you press the shift and color keys one after another or at the same time? (As a shift key would be suspected).